# How do I overload < and >?

Tags: generics, dictionary, freepascal, delphi

I try to create a generic map for two classes.

For this code, the Free Pascal 3.0 compiler displays the errors

> Error: Operator is not overloaded: "TMyTypeA" < "TMyTypeA"
>
> Error: Operator is not overloaded: "TMyTypeA" > "TMyTypeA"

```
unit TestTFPGMap;

{$mode delphi}  

interface

uses
  fgl;

type
  TMyTypeA = class(TObject);
  TMyTypeB = class(TObject);

  TMyMappings = TFPGMap<TMyTypeA, TMyTypeB>;

implementation

end.
```

I have not found a working example for Free Pascal which solves this problem. Do I have to overload the > and < operators, or is there a different way to make this class compile?

Comment: As I understand it, you need to provide `<` and `>` operators for the key type, `TMyTypeA` in your case

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to encapsulate the map as `TFPGMap<Pointer, TMyTypeB>` and use a cast from `TMyTypeA` to `Pointer`.

Comment: @David: just tried everything, and your suggestion (Pointer) is indeed the only way to make this work. The map apparently requires the type to have these overloaded operators (don't ask me how) and AFAICT, classes can't have overloaded operators.